# Cannot access S3 bucket from Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda

I created a simple Lambda function that receives a file as a Base64 string and uploads it to my S3 bucket. I used the default S3 role suggested by the Lambda console:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "logs:CreateLogGroup",
        "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "logs:PutLogEvents"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But I'm still getting an access error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.",
  "errorType": "PermanentRedirect",
  "stackTrace": [
```

Doesn't the `"arn:aws:s3:::*"` cover all my needs? What else do I need to add to use this function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `must be addressed using the specified endpoint` error normally indicates a mismatch between the bucket region and the endpoint that you are calling with your code.

For example: The AWS client connection is established with Sydney but the bucket is in Tokyo.

Try something like this:

```
var s3 = new AWS.S3({region: 'ap-southeast-2'});
```

Comment: Thanks John - now getting a `"Stream yields empty buffer"`, but you solved the original problem.

Answer (score 1):

It might also happens to your sourceKey settings, try to add the exact file path in your S3 like:

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventVersion": "2.0",
      "eventTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "requestParameters": {
        "sourceIPAddress": "127.0.0.1"
      },
      "s3": {
        "configurationId": "testConfigRule",
        "object": {
          "eTag": "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef",
          "sequencer": "0A1B2C3D4E5F678901",
          "key": "images/HappyFace.jpg",
          "size": 1024
        },
        "bucket": {
          "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket",
          "name": "mybucket",
          "ownerIdentity": {
            "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
          }
        },
        "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0"
      },
      "responseElements": {
        "x-amz-id-2": "EXAMPLE123/5678abcdefghijklambdaisawesome/mnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGH",
        "x-amz-request-id": "EXAMPLE123456789"
      },
      "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
      "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
      "userIdentity": {
        "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
      },
      "eventSource": "aws:s3"
    }
  ]
}
```